# The custom payload for the facebook messenger integration only shows up the first time it's called and not thereafter

Tags: facebook, dialogflow-es

I built a winebot that can suggest food pairings or make recommendations.

The integration with FB Messenger works fine, and it's supposed to call a carousel after a search to show you the various options. I found that when I call on it multiple times it will only display the carousel the first time and not a new one each time.

This is the function that calls the carousel

```
  // CREATE RICH MESSAGES FOR FACEBOOK
    function create_carousel(agent, carousel_params) {  
        
      agent.context.set({
        name: 'carousel_output',
        lifespan: 2,
        parameters: carousel_params,
      }); 
      agent.setFollowupEvent('createCarousel');
      agent.add(''); //add a dummy payload
      return; 
    }
```

IntentMap is set up like this:

```
    // Run the proper function handler based on the matched Dialogflow intent name
    let intentMap = new Map();

    intentMap.set('createCarousel', create_carousel);

    agent.handleRequest(intentMap);
```

The createCarousel intent is set up with an event *createCarousel* and an output context called *carousel_output*

Under the messenger tab it has a text message followed by a payload. The text message and payload both use the content of *carousel_output* to make a recommendation.

```
{
  "facebook": {
    "attachment": {
      "type": "template",
      "payload": {
        "elements": [
          {
            "image_url": "#carousel_output.product1.image",
            "default_action": {
              "url": "https://google.com",
              "webview_height_ratio": "tall",
              "type": "web_url"
            },
            "subtitle": "#carousel_output.product1.subtitle",
            "title": "#carousel_output.product1.title",
            "buttons": [
              {
                "url": "https://www.winemag.com/buying-guide/brovia-2013-garblet-sue-barolo/",
                "title": "#carousel_output.product1.price",
                "type": "web_url"
              },
              {
                "title": "Some Text",
                "payload": "Some Text",
                "type": "postback"
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "image_url": "#carousel_output.product2.image",
            "subtitle": "#carousel_output.product2.subtitle",
            "default_action": {
              "type": "web_url",
              "webview_height_ratio": "tall",
              "url": "https://google.com"
            },
            "title": "#carousel_output.product2.title",
            "buttons": [
              {
                "type": "web_url",
                "url": "https://www.wine-searcher.com/find/limerick+lane+cellars+rocky+knoll+zinfandel+russian+river+valley+sonoma+county+north+coast/2013",
                "title": "#carousel_output.product2.price"
              },
              {
                "title": "Some Text",
                "payload": "Some Text",
                "type": "postback"
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "default_action": {
              "webview_height_ratio": "tall",
              "type": "web_url",
              "url": "https://google.com"
            },
            "image_url": "#carousel_output.product3.image",
            "buttons": [
              {
                "title": "#carousel_output.product3.price",
                "type": "web_url",
                "url": "https://www.wine-searcher.com/find/charles+smith+k+vintner+the+hidden+sra+wahluke+slope+washington+usa/2009"
              },
              {
                "title": "Some Text",
                "type": "postback",
                "payload": "Some Text"
              }
            ],
            "title": "#carousel_output.product3.title",
            "subtitle": "#carousel_output.product3.subtitle"
          }
        ],
        "template_type": "generic"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

What I noticed is that when I call the intent a second or third time , the message appears but the payload does not.

I 've already tried clearing output_context and deleting it but this does not seem to affect anything. I looked through the documentation of how payloads work but nothing specifically referencing the issue.
I was wondering if this may be a limitation on facebook messenger but don't see anything in the logs that is a flag. The function runs and the context is updated each time with the right content but just doesn't display in the bot.

Answer (score 0):

The logs didn't show any errors, but the problem appeared in the data provided to the payload.

The code that creates the payload pulls images 3 at a time from a list of urls. There were only 5 urls provided in the list so on the second run it killed the carousel and did not show an undefined error message or a missing data error. Works fine after adding more urls to the list.